# Selective display of an object

Tags: environments

I want to write an exercise sheet for students.
I would like to gather the questions, the hints, and the proofs at the same place in the .tex file.

Then I want to display the questions, the hints and the proofs in specific
parts of the .tex.

The pseudo-code would look like :

```
\begin{exercise}[my_exercise_1]%my_exercise_1 would be the label of the exercise
    \name Continuum hypothesis
    \difficulty \easy
    \question Prove...
    \hint You should think about this...
    \solution You just have to...
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[my_exercise_2]
    \name Pythagorian Theorem
    \difficulty \advanced
    \question My question is...
    \hint You should think about this...
    \solution You just have to...
\end{exercise}

\section{Questions}
% do something to print the question of my_exercice_1
% do something to print the question of my_exercice_2

\section{Hints}
% do something to print the hints of my_exercice_1
% do something to print the hints of my_exercice_2

\section{Solutions}
% do something to print solution of my_exercice_1
% do something to print solution of my_exercice_2
```

Since I don't want to miss the display of a question or a solution, then having an automated display would be nice.

I count on you guys!
Many thanks,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Packages `exsheets`, `answers`, `probsoln` are doing (all?) this requests. Pseudo code isn't really helpful, sometime

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Is this a duplicate? It seems familiar but I can't find anything specific.

Comment: @cfr: I don't know